# Launching Chrome without web-securities in VS Code

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

How can I configure the Chrome Browser without web-security in `launch.json` file in VS Code? I installed the VS Code extension **Debugger for Chrome** and my launch.json seems so:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8100/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

This code launch Chrome with web-securities. How can I configure this file so that I can launch Chrome with this parameter: `chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 39):

just add

```
"runtimeArgs": [
   "--disable-web-security"
],
```

So your launch.json will look like:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8100/",
      "runtimeArgs": [
         "--disable-web-security"
       ],
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked for me on Windows machine `"runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security","--user-data-dir=c:\\chrome-browser"]`.

Comment: For me where `type` was `blazorwasm` putting this in `browserConfig` worked. `"browserConfig": { "runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security","--user-data-dir=c:\\chrome-browser"]},`