# Unable to load external scripts when debugging JavaScript in VisualStudioCode because of CORS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, cors, vscode-debugger

I want to debug my client-side JavaScript code in [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (VSC). However, I want to avoid setting up an external live server and want to just load the files from my local drive. Because of this I created the following `launch.json`:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome from the file system",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

This executes well, when starting the debugger with `F5` in VSC, Chrome opens and loads my `index.html` from the `src` folder.

However, I get the following error message when trying to import my `index.js` file like this `<script src="./index.js" type="module" defer></script>`:

> Access to script at 'file:///home/matrix/odin-battleship/src/index.js'
> from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
> requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
> chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

I know that this is a safety measure, which prevents websites from accessing my files. I've read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local). However, I just want to debug my code without creating a live-server. I came across starting Chrome with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416029/launching-chrome-without-web-securities-in-vs-code) explains how to launch Chrome from `launch.json` with flags.

**Is this the right attempt, or are there better solutions to debug your files from your local storage in VSC?**

Answer (score -1):

As you have mentioned, it is a security policy enforced by the browser to prevent the website owners from accessing the files on your computer.

You should start distributing this `js` file from any servers. That way your `scheme` will be `http` or `https` and the file can be served safely over to the browser.